# FollowJointTrajectoryAction feasibility checking

Tags: ros, moveit, follow-joint-trajectory, ros-kinetic, movegroup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

MoveIt seems to do some sanity checking before executing trajectories and I was wondering if using the `follow_joint_trajectory` action gets you those same checks.  I sent a bad trajectory that didn't start from the current pose today in simulation and expected an error but instead I got a instantaneous jump in the robots simulated state (very bad).  I was expecting an error such as [this](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/283) but just got straight up execution.

1. Is this expected behavior?
2. Should I perhaps wrap my trajectory with a `MoveGroup::Plan` and then execute via `MoveGroup::execute(const Plan &plan)` call?  Do I get other checks this way as well like collisions, joint limits, etc.?

Edit: In this particular case I am using a move group on top of `industrial_robot_simulator`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305963/followjointtrajectoryaction-feasibility-checking/) by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 525 on 2018-10-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2018-10-18**:
Just to post a follow-up here... I switched from using control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectory Action (provided by drivers) directly to moveit_msgs/ExecuteTrajectory Action provided by the move group.  This gets me checks from both MoveIt and the driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I was wondering if using the `follow_joint_trajectory` action gets you those same checks

Who is providing that action server? That is going to be the answer here.

If the server does not implement those checks, nothing will be checked.

---

> I found this check in the `ur_modern_driver` [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver/blob/master/src/ur_ros_wrapper.cpp#L347).  So my problem is that `industrial_robot_simulator` doesn't have the equivalent?  And the checks are then driver-dependent?

Yes. That is why I asked whether you could clarify what you were doing.

Specific drivers implement specific checks, but MoveIt also has some checks.

The `industrial_robot_simulator` does not do any checking and just executes whatever it receives.

It's also not a simulator: it's more a visualiser for trajectories with a similar interface to a nr of ROS-I robot drivers.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2018-10-17**:
So I'm using MoveIt on top of `ros_industrial_simulator`.   In this case would I expect to find the checks in `JointTrajectoryAction::goalCB(JointTractoryActionServer::GoalHandle gh)`?  I guess I am confused because I thought I have gotten errors in the past but didn't this time.

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2018-10-17**:
I found this check in the `ur_modern_driver` [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver/blob/master/src/ur_ros_wrapper.cpp#L347).  So my problem is that `industrial_robot_simulator` doesn't have the equivalent?  And the checks are then driver-dependent?

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2018-10-17**:
I have also just discovered MoveIt's `TrajectoryExecutionManager::validate` that produces the "Invalid Trajectory: start point deviates from current robot state..."  error.  This might be what I was looking for.  This gets called when using moveit but not the joint trajectory action directly.